# discord.py как сделать так ,чтобы бот одновременно выполнял пассивную работу и отвечать на вопросы?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import random
import time
import asyncio

#connect+token

TOKEN = 'ODM0Njg5NDc1NjYwNzQyNjY2.YIEjJg.6yd7H73U7fmFfwQM-EvvQ47OvSU'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
#prefix !

#идея команд боту
starts=['bot','бот']
answer=['Да, я тут ' , 'Да , я Вас слушаю','паша лох']


#удаление сообщений

@bot.command()
async def clear( ctx , amount=100  ):
    print('faza 2')
    author=ctx.message.author
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount)
    await ctx.send(f'я удалил сообщения как вы и просили { author.mention }')
    time.sleep(2)
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1)


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print('faza 1')
    author=ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send('Mr '+f'{ author.mention }   Рад Вас видеть')



@bot.event
#ответ бота на выражние
async def on_message( message ):
    msg=message.content.lower()
    if msg in starts :
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(answer))
        



bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: 1. Никогда никому не показывайте токен вашего бота. Сейчас у людей есть полный контроль над ботом. Поэтому советую как можно скорее зайти на страницу вашего бота на сайте https://discord.com/developers и сгенерировать новый токен

2. `on_message()` является событием бота, поэтому добавьте над этой функцией декоратор `@bot.event`. Чтобы работала команда `!test`, над функцией `aync def test(ctx)` добавьте декоратор `@bot.command()`

Comment: спасибо , токен не рабочий я его поменял раньше чем загрузил его сюда , но он все равно не работает точнее тепперь работает только on_message

Comment: Какая-то ошибка есть?

Comment: нет из 3 функций работает только 1  то есть on_message  которая bot.event остальные 2 которые bot.command  не рабочие

Comment: я попробовал поставить в эти функции print чтобы понять что они рабочие , но оно не принтует

Comment: потому что, я же вам специально указал, что `bot.event` без скобок, а `bot.command()` со скобками должен быть. В этом дело?

Comment: `bot.event` `bot.command()` так и написано

Comment: Обновите код в тексте вопроса на текущий, если вам не сложно

Comment: А вы команду как вызываете в чате? Вот так? `!test`

Comment: нет я уже поменял на `.` но если вы про это то `.test`

Comment: Ага, понял. У вас событие `on_message()` отлавливает все сообщения, которые видит бот. После этого функция отрабатывает и все. Нужно, чтобы бот сначала сканировал полученное сообщение на наличие в нем команды. Для этого в функцию `on_message()` добавьте строку `await bot.process_commands(message)`